# Popup keybinding in wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Is it possible to bind key pressed in wpf popup?

I try it like this, but seems no effect:

```
<Popup.InputBindings>
   <KeyBinding Key="Escape" Command="Close" />
   <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding NewDateSelectedCommand}" />
</Popup.InputBindings>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can, you must set Focus() into the popup

```
<Popup x:Name="popup">
    <Popup.InputBindings>
       <KeyBinding Key="Escape" Command="Close" />
       <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding NewDateSelectedCommand}" />
    </Popup.InputBindings>
</Popup>

public void ShowPopup()
{
    this.popup.IsOpen = true;
    this.popup.Focus();
}
```